# Easyer way to call mixin SASS instead of @include

Tags: css, sass, less, font-size, pixel

I am currently using a mixing for rem font-sizes with a fallback to pixels in SASS, for responsive font sizes. I'm using this mixin:

```
@mixin font-size ($size) { 
    $remValue: $size / 16; 
    $pxValue: ($size); 
    font-size: $pxValue + px; 
    font-size: $remValue + rem; 
}
```

Now i was wondering if there's a shorter way to call on this mixin.
Now i have to type:

```
@include font-size(20);
```

*For a size of 20 pixels (1.25rem)*

Witch is good, to set for a couple of font-sizes, but if i have to use it more than 30 times it's getting annoying...

Now i saw that LESS uses:

```
.font-size(20);
```

To do the same thing, witch is better but for now i need to use SASS.
Can i make this call shorter or do i still need to use @include?
I could not find a emmet shortcode for this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't, as you can see in [SASS Docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html)

[image: SS]

Comment: Sadly... :(

Guess i have to make a Emmet shortcode for it or something...

Answer (score 0):

> Can i make this call shorter or do i still need to use @include?

A shorter method currently doesn't exist in Sassy CSS (SCSS). But in pure SASS you simply might as well use `+` instead of `@include`.

Example

```
=font-size($size) 
    $remValue: $size / 16 
    $pxValue: ($size)
    font-size: $pxValue + px
    font-size: $remValue + rem    

.selector
    +font-size(20) // <- that + here
```

Note that you have to rename your file format into `.sass` as this only applies to the SASS syntax originaly based on Ruby.